# Why do i have double scroll bar with an off canvas menu implemented?

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the page http://artesanoshop.com/index.php?id_category=9&controller=category&id_lang=1

I tried aplying this menu to my page:http://tympanus.net/Development/MultiLevelPushMenu/index3.html

It has something to do with the footer, because it behaves in a strange manner.

its an off canvas menu, my home page is fine but all the other pages have double scroll bars.

How can i fix this to mantain the menu working and the page with only one scroll bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another fix: add negative margin to adjust for the footer height.

```
.mpcontainer{
    margin-bottom: -35px;
}
```

EDIT:

Ignore the above suggestion, and move the

```
<footer id="footer">...</footer>
```

inside

```
<div class="scroller">...</div>
```

just under

```
<div class="scroller-inner">...</div>
```

Side note: Since moving the `<footer>` away from the actual page footer, isn't aesthetically correct - maybe change it into a div, and call it something else.

Comment: Thanks anyway i'll continue to figure it out this was a clue.

Comment: The footer sticks to the bottom of the page which should not happen

Comment: I see the problem, I'v edited the answer with a better solution (though not a pretty one)

Comment: Thanks, now it extends to the whole page width. But this solution works. Its not great to have one width on the home page and one on the rest but i'll figure out how to change it.

Comment: It works i have fixed it closing the divs properly everything is godd thanks a lot for your help really.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both

```
.scroller {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and

```
html, body, .mpcontainer, .scroller {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And your content scrolls regularly with the page scrollbar.

Comment: thanks but the problem is that if i do that then the off canvas menu becomes the same height as the page.

Comment: The weird thing for me is that this is not happening on the home page.

Comment: I may be missing something but in chrome I don't see any difference in the behaviour of the menu when I remove these styles...